# Exchange 2016 Migration from Exchange 2003 with 2003 Servers in Forest

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

I am planning a migration from Exchange 2003 to 2016 and now learned that it requires a forest functional level 2008 or greater.

We have some newer 2016 and 2012 servers, but have multiple 2003 servers left on the domain and can't raise the level which leave me with two options... Deploy Exchange 2013, or Install 2016 in a different tree in the forest?

All of our servers, machines and users all currently reside within a "company.local" namespace which is at 2003 level split into different sites for each of our 40 remote office locations (spoke and hub)

If a was to create a "company.com" domain for this new 2016 Server with Exchange 2016 will I be able to add and manage the users in the .local domain? Would I need to setup any sort of trusts between the two? I really don't want to move the users them from their current containers because of Group Policy, Applications pushed and Roaming profiles.

Exchange 2003 really works nice within user manager... and I hate playing with a live domain without some professional opinions ;)

Any suggestions from anyone with experience with the above would be greatly appreciated :)

Kind Regards,
Mike

Comment: We have 2017 and you are really running multiple Windows 2003 Server which are reached the [EOL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003) level? As you are running so much old stuff, please keep also noted that you must run Office 2010 for Exchange 2016 every else will not work...

Comment: I know it's 2017... the Servers are all isolated and just for local File&Print, but yes I agree it's time! As far as Office 2010, we currently use that because nothing else will work with Exchange 2003. Are you stating that Office 2013/16  wont work with Exchange 2016?

Comment: I mean Office 2010 is the latest "older" version which can be used with Exchange 2016. Office 2007/2003 will not work.